# Find Respondents To Reserve - Groups

Tags: acl

Looks to me like there's an issue that needs fixing, but I want to check to see if I've missed something.

I'm testing functionality of walklists.  The User-Contact is limited to a subset of contact data (a ward in a city) via an Access List.  The limitation works as expected when searching, creating groups, etc.  When I get to the 'Find Respondents To Reserve' panel, things go a little haywire.  If I don't specify an entry in the 'Group(s)' field, the result set can include contacts outside the ward/city (e.g. a street name that exists in multiple cities), thus *'breaking' the ACL*.  If I instead pick the ACL from the Group(s) drop down (the only one I happen to have available) then all is well.

Shouldn't the Group(s) field behave something like:

1) If User-Contact not in an ACL, then Group(s) field defaults blank and allows any Contact to be Reserved.
2) If User-Contact is in an ACL Group, then Group(s) defaults to one of the ACL groups, and allows any other ACL Groups to which User-Contact belongs to be picked from the Group(s) drop down.

Ken